# VBA: Meet three criteria in a row and output average of other cells of these rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to search Rows in an Excel-File in which three criteria are met. They are in Columns K, L and AJ. If those Kriterias are met I want to look at the Price (Column AM). If there are multiple Rows who meet the criteria, I find an average price and You can see it in the output cell.

I dont know what I am doing wrong. I always get the MsgBox from the last if loop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks a lot!

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindAndAverage()

    Dim findenPN As String
    Dim findenVend As String
    Dim findenWS As String
    Dim Preis As Double
    Dim Added As Double
    Dim Anzahl As Long
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim RowMax As Long
    Dim Avrg As Double

    'fill Variables 
    findenPN = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C3").Value
    findenPN = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C4").Value
    findenPN = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C5").Value
    Preis = 0
    Added = 0
    Anzahl = 0
    iRow = 2
    Avrg = 0

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

        RowMax = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        For iRow = 2 To RowMax

            If Cells(iRow, 12).Value = findenPN And Cells(iRow, 11).Value = findenVend And Cells(iRow, 36).Value = findenWS Then

                'Look fpor price in column AM 
                Preis = Cells(iRow, 39).Value

                'Add price to other results
                Added = Added + Preis

                'go to next row
                iRow = iRow + 1

                'Add one for Average
                Anzahl = Anzahl + 1

            Else
                iRow = iRow + 1

            End If

        Next iRow

    End With

    If Anzahl > 0 Then

        'Output in Sheet2
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate

        Avrg = Added / Anzahl

        Range("C9").Value = Avrg

        End With

    Else

        MsgBox ("Kein Ergebniss!")

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What type of values are stored in Cells(iRow, 12), Cells(iRow, 11) & Cells(iRow, 36)? Make sure you are not comparing Integers with String.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your code (the if-statement is a good place), observe the values of your `finden`-variables and the cell-values  and see where it fails. Anyhow, **remove the `iRow = iRow + 1`-statements**. The increment is done automatically by the `for`-loop (that's the idea of a `for`-loop)

Comment: You are overwriting  findenPN twice . I think you mean to change the variable name for each ie. findenPN, findenVend and findenWS this maybe why your condition cannot be met. So change these lines...... findenPN = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C3").Value etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped! Sometimes copy paste isnt the best idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring 3 variables but you are leaving 2 empty for the rest of the code, validation will never meet this way.

```
Dim findenPN As String
Dim findenVend As String
Dim findenWS As String

'fill Variables 
findenPN = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C3").Value
findenPN = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C4").Value
findenPN = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C5").Value
```

You are missing to declare `findenVend` and `findenWS` Values.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need VBA for that. Worksheet formula would be enough:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Sheet1!M:M,Sheet1!K:K,Sheet1!C3,Sheet1!L:L,Sheet1!C4,Sheet1!AJ:AJ,Sheet1!C5)
```